# How to solve "Expression pattern of type 'Bool' cannot match values of type 'Double'" in Swift switch statement

Tags: xcode, function, switch-statement

Im trying to use switch statement instead of if statement for learning purpose. But Xcode kept showing me this error. I don't understand how to solve this problem as I'm relatively new to programming. The error is at the switch statement

```
func damage(cRate: Double, cDmg: Double, attempt: Int) -> [Int] {
    cRateSimple = cRate.rounded()
    cDmgSimple = cDmg.rounded()

for _ in 1...attempt {
    doesItCrit = Double.random(in: 1.0...100.0)
    switch doesItCrit {
    case doesItCrit <= cRate:
      print("CRITICAL")
    case doesItCrit > cRate:
      print("no Crit")
    return damageArray
    }
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that you are `switch`ing on a `Double` but the value in the cases is a `Bool`. This is not allowed. The type in the cases must match the type to be switched on.

A valid syntax is

```
switch doesItCrit {
    case _ where doesItCrit <= cRate:
       print("CRITICAL")
    case _ where doesItCrit > cRate:
       print("no Crit")
       return damageArray
    default: break
}
```